# Ajax And PHP : Handling Multiple Posts in A Single Page

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am developing a webpage where multiple posts from the Database is shown one by one in a single page much like twitter or facebook. 
I need to use Ajax for comments and likes. The comment system should be nested as well.

The problem I am having is each post is having a unique post_id and I need to transfer it through Ajax for inserting the comments into the DB.

The below HTML is inside a PHP for loop for getting the posts from Database. So I have given post_id as every comment element's id to get the unique post comment.

```js
<script>
                function addcomment(abc) {
                    var temp1 = abc;
                    var post_id = temp1.value; // POST ID
                    
                    var comment = document.getElementById(post_id).value;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "addcomment.php",
                        data: {
                            post_id:post_id,
                            comment:comment
                        },
                        success: function(response) {
                            document.getElementsByClassName(post_id).innerHTML = response;
                        }
                    });
                }
</script>
```

```html
<div class="comment_section" id="comment_section">
    <textarea type="text" id="<?php echo($post_id); ?>" placeholder="comment Here..." value=""></textarea>
    <button id="comment_button" value="<?php echo ($post_id); ?>" onclick="return addcomment(this);">Comment</button>
    <br>
    <span class="<?php echo($post_id); ?>"></span>
</div>
```

And the addcomment.php looks like this:

```html
<?php
include("connect.php");
$postid = $_POST['post_id'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO comments (name,comment) VALUES ('$postid','$comment')";
$result = $db->query($sql1);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1";
$result1 = $db->query($sql);


while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
    
    $post = $row['name'];
    $comment_op = $row['comment'];
?>

    <?php echo $comment_op; ?>
    <br>
    <?php echo $post; ?>

    <?php } ?>
```

How can I get the comment when the Comment button clicked and store it in the DB and return the Comment below the comment area using AJAX ?

Comment: Yes, I know. I will prepare the query before executing. But I am having a much big problem and like to hear from you on that.

Comment: <span class="<?php echo($post_id); ?>"></span> you should put the post_id in an input hidden field like   <input type='hidden' id='postid' name='postid' value="<?php echo($post_id); ?>">

Comment: Then if its mysqli you are using you probably need to close the previous statement, before executing the next

Comment: @Ezekiel For Displaying The Comment ? Or For Getting it From the TextArea?

Comment: I don't quite understand how you have an id for a comment before it is posted?

Comment: @GraemeChapman The comment division is inside a for loop which is used to loop through the database which contains a number of posts. So, I want to get the posts one after another in a single page. Each post has a unique id in the database which is what i mentioned here as post_id. Thus every post has a unique id every and under every post there is a comment section which also have the same unique id: post_id.

Answer (score 0):

For display comments on specific post first you create comment section and use

```
<section id="comments-post_id"></section>
```

when you successfully add comment via above ajax request code get the response and create comment html and append in your comment section.

```
$("#comments-post_id").html($response);
```

make sure you have already create your comment HTML in controller or in ajax file where you get the response.

and for the rendering all post data user inside loop or recursive function to get all comments of your specific post

Need more help feel free and ask :)